# Probability of $3$ doubles when two dice roled $4$ times

Tags: probability, dice

I thought that when rolling two dices to get only pairs is for a single roll  $\frac{1}{6}$ for two $\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2$, and for three $\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3$.

But since I have 4 rolls I could get the three doubles with 4 possible solutions, i.e. $4\times\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3$. Since I can as well obtain a double I have $\left(+ \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^4\right)$

i.e. $4 \times \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^4$

but somehow this is incorrect. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a "double" in exactly $3$ out of $4$ rolls:

$$\binom43\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{3}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{4-3}$$

---

Get a "double" in at least $3$ out of $4$ rolls:

$$\sum\limits_{n=3}^{4}\binom4n\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{4-n}$$

Comment: Perhaps I didn't clearly formulate the q. I wanted to have the prob for three (or four) doubles when I roll two dices at once four times. I would have guessed your first answer is 'Get exactly three doubles in 4 rolls' - or am I wrong? That would match somehow my q but your wordings does indicate something else. Therefore the q

Comment: @LeO: 1. Yes, you have formulated the question extremely unclear, so I pretty much guessed what your intention was. 2. Yes, my first answer is 'Get exactly $3$ doubles in $4$ rolls'. 3. It remains unclear what exactly your question is, but I believe that if you study the two answers above, then you'll be able to answer any other question that you might have under the current settings (for example, 'Get exactly $4$ doubles in $4$ rolls').